# Box shadow on top, bottom and left only

Tags: css, box-shadow

I want to add the box-shadow just to top, bottom and left sides only - no right side.

This is my CSS class:

```
.topBottomLeft{
      box-shadow: inset -1px 0px 0.5px 0.5px #000,inset 0 1px 0.5px 0.5px #000,inset 0 -1px 0.5px 0.5px #000 !important;
}
```

This is my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Ly4tocny/

It is applying the box shadow however to all four sides. What am I missing?

Comment: The property doesn't really work like that.

Comment: It would be better for you to use a pseudo-element to add the inset shadow (with spread radius) only to three sides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close to a solution. You just need to tweak the values a bit.

Here is a working example with your method, with some added emphasis so you can see the changes I made.

```
    box-shadow: inset 0 5px 0.5px 0.5px #000,
    inset 0 -5px 0.5px 0.5px #000,
    inset  5px 0.5px 0.5px #000;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ercnvzj7/

I recommend this, for future shading: http://css3generator.com/

Answer (score 2):

The first inset value should be 1 not -1.

```
.topBottomLeft {
    box-shadow: inset 1px 0px 0.5px 0.5px #000,inset 0 1px 0.5px 0.5px #000,inset 0 -1px 0.5px 0.5px #000;
}
```

Comment: There would still be a small shadow on the right (atleast on Chrome).

Comment: Play with negative value, for example 'inset 4px 0 0.5px -2px #000'.

Comment: But then the thickness won't be same as what OP is expecting. I will leave that to the OP to decide :)

Comment: OP use 1px thickness. If so, I would use `border: 1px solid #000; border-width: 1px 0 1px 1px; box-sizing: border-box;` instead.

Comment: I don't intend to stalk you, so don't mistake me. You do realise the difference between a 1px border and a 1px shadow with 0.5px spread radius right? They aren't the same :)

Comment: Based on the solution that has been accepted, it seems like OP was looking for borders than box-shadows. So, your comment was correct :)